# How to color box with container class?

Tags: html, css

I try define two boxes with color blue and green using a container. The purpose is to study the property of `flexbox`.  But I don't understand why I am missing in my code, it doesn't work...Thanks for your help guys !

[image]

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
  width:50%;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
  width:50;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box blue">

</div>
<div class="box green">

</div>
</div>
```

I want to draw 2 boxes with 50% width in blue and green, each one in one container

Comment: `width: 50` is not valid. also please add your code here and don't post screenshots.

Comment: two issue (1) missing % in the second width (2) height with percentage value will fail

Comment: add float property to the blue and green div. And correct the css like what @Temani Afif told in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row same-line">

<div class="col-md-6 box blue"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 box green"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and use this css

```
.blue{
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:50%;
}
.green{
  background:green;
  height:50px;
  width:50%;
}
.same-line{
  display:inline-flex;
  width:100%;
}
```

and here is working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/d5hxc0qu/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `height:100%` on your `body` and `html` and `container` to make it work:

```css
body,html, .container{
    height:100%;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
  width:50%;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box blue">

</div>
<div class="box green">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In flex don't use width, use       `flex: 0 0 50%;` instead of `width:50%`

See working example:

```css
body,
html,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you eirenaios for the proposition not using width :)

Comment: @Eric Yage if it is helpful, you can accept the answer.